# Refering to a TextBox in Cell in Grid View

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

So I made a `ListView` with `GridView` in its view prop :

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="TicketListView" Margin="20,5,20,5">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Owned" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Owned}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price, ConverterCulture='en-US', StringFormat={}{0:C2}}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Amount">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox MinWidth="20" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Bought, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>                
        ...
</ListView>
```

I want to focus on specific `TextBox` when selecting item in this list view, so you dont have to click on the `TextBox` to write but instead you can click on item (row) and start changing its value. (Hopefully you understand ;( )

Is this possible or should I do this list another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event for the `ListViewItem` and get a reference to the `TextBox` using the `VisualTreeHelper` class:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="TicketListView">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="TicketListView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Owned" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Owned}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price, ConverterCulture='en-US', StringFormat={}{0:C2}}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Amount">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox MinWidth="20" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Bought, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

---

```
private void TicketListView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = sender as ListViewItem;
    TextBox textBox = GetChildOfType<TextBox>(lvi);
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        textBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            bool b = textBox.Focus();
            Keyboard.Focus(textBox);
        }));
    }
}

private static T GetChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj == null)
        return null;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
        var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to thank you... Where do you know all this from?

Answer (score -2):

on listitem changed event
do,

```
TextBox.focus();
TextBox.text=List1.selectedValue.Tostting();
```